# Debug help! I keep getting garbage here (sometimes)

Tags: php

Sometimes when I play with the input of this function (dates) I get garbage, description:

```
<?php 


function optimized_subscription_total($active_sub_time,$arr_sub_values)
{

    // This function takes a row from the DB where prices for each period of time usage is listed. there are prices for 1 month, 3 months,6 and 12 months.

    // when the user has subscribed for 12 months, and the user asks for a refund, after they used 9 months and 6 days for example, the system treats the refund as if they subscribed for (in months) COST_6 + COST_3 + (COST_1/30)*6 
    // the result of the function is then subtracted from the amount they actually paid and is considered the refund.

    // $arr_sub_values is the associative row from the DB, containing the prices
    // $active_sub_time is measured in months and is a double

    $result=0;
    if(($active_sub_time-6)>=0)
    {
        $active_sub_time-=6;
        $result+=($arr_sub_values['COST_6']);
    }
    if(($active_sub_time-3)>=0)
    {
        $active_sub_time-=3;
        $result+=($arr_sub_values['COST_3']);
    }

    while(($active_sub_time-1)>=0)
    {
        $active_sub_time-=1;
        $result+=($arr_sub_values['COST_1']);
    }

    if($active_sub_time>0)
        $result+=($active_sub_time)*($arr_sub_values['COST_1']);

    return $result;
}



$datetime1 = date_create('2009-12-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2010-11-09');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$num_of_months = ($interval->format('%y'))*12+($interval->format('%m'))+($interval->format('%a'))/30;
echo "<br />";

$v = array('COST_1'=>'3.99','COST_3'=>'9.99','COST_6'=>'15.99','COST_12'=>'25.99');
echo "OPT value for $num_of_months months=" . optimized_subscription_total($num_of_months, $v);


?>
```

I can't make out why I get :

```
OPT value for 10 months=M.97
```

as a result here. I think I need to get a float number, no ?

I was expecting the result of the function that should be "OPT value for 10 months=29.97", as it should take COST_6 + COST_3 + COST_1... but I get that weird M.97, and sometimes things like POKHHHG.97

Here's the same function rewritten:

```
    function optimized_subscription_total($active_sub_time,$arr_subscription_values)
{

    $result=0;


while(($active_sub_time-12)>=0)
{
    $active_sub_time-=12;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_12']);
}

if(($active_sub_time-6)>=0)
{
    $active_sub_time-=6;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_6']);
}
if(($active_sub_time-3)>=0)
{
    $active_sub_time-=3;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_3']);
}

while(($active_sub_time-1)>=0)
{
    $active_sub_time-=1;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_1']);
}

if($active_sub_time>0)
    $result+=($active_sub_time)*($arr_subscription_values['COST_1']);

return $result;
```

}

I just hope this doesn't break. But can someone tell me what could have been wrong on the first version ?
What could that be ?

**edit:** I made this bug appear after refreshing the page around 10 times, Now I get a weird I.004 
Thanks !!

Comment: Your exact code for me in PHP 5.3.3 produces `OPT value for 21.1 months=74.259`

Comment: i have this "OPT value for 210.5 months=829.965" on php 5.3.5

Comment: am I doing something wrong ? the results are different already

Comment: Hey I just recreated the bug after around 7-10 times of refreshing the page. similar ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to accomplish is quite easy, assuming a month consists of 31 days (which it doesn't). DateTime::diff() assumes this. You'd probably want treat the 28 days of February as a complete month, though?!

```
<?php

function calculateRealCost($started, $ended) {
    // month values
    $_month = array(
        12 => 25.99,
        6 => 15.99,
        3 => 9.99,
        1 => 3.99
    );
    // assuming a median of 30 days per month. 
    // it's closer to 30.4 days per month, though.
    $_day = $_month[1] / 30;

    $price = 0;

    // identify the time span
    $started = $started instanceof DateTime ? $started : new DateTime($started);
    $ended = $ended instanceof DateTime ? $ended : new DateTime($ended);
    // you should note that diff() treat's the last day inclusive, so it may be "a day short"
    $diff = $started->diff($ended);

    // add years (12 months)
    $price += $_month[12] * $diff->y;

    // add months
    $months = $diff->m;
    foreach ($_month as $m => $v) {
        while ($m <= $months) {
            $price += $v;
            $months -= $m;
        }
    }
    // add days
    $price += $_day * $diff->d;

    // return rounded to two decimals
    return round($price, 2);
}

$test = array(
    // 0 years 10 months, 29 days
    // 15.99 + 9.99 + 3.99 + (0.133 * 29)
    array('start' => "2009-12-11", 'end' => "2010-11-09", 'cost' => 33.83),
    // 1 years 10 months, 27 days 
    // 25.99 + 15.99 + 9.99 + 3.99 + (0.133 * 27)
    array('start' => "2009-12-11", 'end' => "2011-11-07", 'cost' => 59.55),
    // 0 years 0 months, 28 days
    // (0.133 * 28)
    array('start' => "2011-02-01", 'end' => "2011-03-01", 'cost' => 3.72), 
    // 0 years 0 months, 29 days
    // (0.133 * 29)
    array('start' => "2012-02-01", 'end' => "2012-03-01", 'cost' => 3.86), 
    // 0 years 1 months, 29 days
    // 3.99 + (0.133 * 29)
    array('start' => "2011-09-01", 'end' => "2011-10-31", 'cost' => 7.85), 
);

foreach ($test as $t) {
    $res = calculateRealCost($t['start'], $t['end']);
    if ($res != $t['cost']) {
        echo "{$t['start']} to {$t['end']} expected {$t['cost']} but got {$res}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rodneyrehm for the example. I have my function working right now (I just added the new version to the question) I hope this doesn't break again. I wasn't sure why you rewrote it, I'd love it if you could explain some more. Thanks

Comment: I rewrote the function to (a) show you an approach that would easily allow you to introduce a 4-month-price without altering any code. (b) show you `$interval->format('%y')` == `$interval->y`. (c) make heads and tails of how `DateInterval` identifies a month (31 days flat, no calendar support here. "February" being 28 days is not treated as a whole month).

Comment: Could you locate why I get garbage by any chance ?

Comment: I made this bug appear after refreshing the page around 10 times, Now I get a weird I.004 ....